# Autostart synergy server on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lightdm, autostart, synergy

How do I configure synergy to start automatically as sever after login?

I have found the following tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto#On_the_server but it seems a bit outdated. My ubuntu installation uses LigthDM as display manager. The tutorial tells me to edit the /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file, but the file does not exist. It seems that editing the lightdm.conf file is deprecated. I do not know what file I now should edit in order to autostart synergy as server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Synergy as startup program fixes my problem.

1. Open `Startup Applications` and click on `Add`
2. Enter name: `Synergy`
3. Enter command: `synergy`
4. Click on `save`

Next time you restart the computer, Synergy will automatically start.